# Why is button not pushing to ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I have created login/register functionality successfully in my iOS app using Firebase, but then I encounter a problem when the user gets logged in.

I am trying to create a menu page (HomeVC) where a button leads to a new view controller (second view controller), however when the button is pressed nothing happens.

When I add a segue from 'HomeVC' to 'SecondViewController' the button works, but the view controller appears as a modal and is not part of the navigation.

```
    class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapButton(){
        navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController(), animated: true)
    }
        
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.title = "MY SECOND PAGE"
            view.backgroundColor = .red
```

[storyboards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xac7.png)

Comment: have u got solution? have u tried below answers?

Comment: thanks everyone for the solutions but unfortunately none worked. I must have set something up wrong on the register/login functionality that is causing the button to not work. Trying to figure it out now

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Note:- Please add identifier in storyboard

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil) // Assuming "Main" is your storyboard name
 let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "aaaa") // add "aaaa" as storyboard id for that view controller in Main storyboard
 navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, but you should explain why: "You can't just create a view controller with an empty initializer like `SecondViewController()`. That will create an instance of your view controller class with no view contents. You need to instantiate it from your storyboard."

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this as well**

you must give Storyboard Id as `SecondViewController`

```
 let viewController: SecondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

or try like this

```
 self.navigationController?.present(SecondViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The storyboard identifier can be "Fred" if you want it to be. You just need to use the Storyboard Identifier that you set up in Interface Builder.